# Delete only when there are two (or more) 1s

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to remove element from a nested list when they have a certain number of elements repeated. For example:

```
{{1,2,3,4},{1,1,2,3},{1,3,4,1},{1,4,2,4}}
```

I would like to remove the 2nd and 3rd sublists because they have 2 cases of the 1. I would like the end result to remain nested however.

```
{{1,2,3,4},{1,4,2,4}}
```

I believe that Delete cases and count will be used to solve this problem.

Comment: So you mean, not "greater than 2", but "greater than or equal to 2"?

Comment: Will it always be 2 or do you want to generalise to an arbitrary threshold?

Comment: I am using 2 as a arbitrary threshold. Also it would be greater than or equal to 2.

Comment: The 4th sublist has two cases of a `4` -- should it be removed, too?

Comment: No it should only be the 1s

Comment: ``Select[#, Count[#, 1] < 2 &] &@ {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 4,
    1}, {1, 4, 2, 4}}`` gives you the list of lists that have "1" not more than 1 time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Using `Select`:

```
Select[list, Count[#, 1] < 2 &]
```

Using `Cases`:

```
Cases[list, l_ /; Count[l, 1] < 2]
```

Also if the threshold is at 2, then this `DeleteCases` version might also be an option (but it gets ugly when you want a greater threshold):

```
DeleteCases[list, {___, 1, ___, 1, ___}]
```

As garej points out you can also turn the `Cases` solution into `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[list, l_ /; Count[l, 1] > 1]
```

Or use `Replace` for the pattern matching:

```
Replace[list, {___, 1, ___, 1, ___} -> Nothing, 1]
```

However, out of all of these, the pattern matching solutions are actually fastest:

```
list = RandomInteger[4, {500, 4}];
RepeatedTiming[Select[list, Count[#, 1] < 2 &];]
RepeatedTiming[Cases[list, l_ /; Count[l, 1] < 2];]
RepeatedTiming[DeleteCases[list, l_ /; Count[l, 1] > 1];]
RepeatedTiming[DeleteCases[list, {___, 1, ___, 1, ___}];]
RepeatedTiming[Replace[list, {___, 1, ___, 1, ___} -> Nothing, 1];]

(* {0.000919, Null}
   {0.00094, Null}
   {0.00093, Null}
   {0.00038, Null}
   {0.000253, Null} *)
```

But note that once you go to bigger thresholds, the pattern matching becomes expensive. It's still fastest for some other small thresholds, but around a threshold of 10, the speed is comparable to that of the other three solutions. When you go to a threshold of 20, then the pattern matching is ten times slower than the other solutions.

Comment: would it be possible to add an OR/AND to this and add another criteria

Comment: @Andre In the first two cases, easily.  Just use `&&` or `||` after `Count[..., 1] < 2` and your additional criteria.

Comment: As regards the last approach, when the threshold increases one could replace the pattern by `Riffle[ConstantArray[___, threshold + 1], 1]`

Comment: @Coolwater Sure, but I think the pattern matching will become a lot more expensive than a simple `Count` and it's also pretty obscure code whereas the first solution is very readable.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, why not `DeleteCases[data, l_ /; Count[l, 1] > 1]`

Comment: @garej Because a) it's fundamentally the same as the `Cases` solution but I don't think it's clearer, b) I wanted to show a different approach, c) for a threshold of two the pattern matching is actually more than twice as fast as any of the other solutions. (I guess I should add the timings to the answer.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner, I see you point with readability; I would also add this version: `Replace[list, {___, 1, ___, 1, ___} -> Nothing, 1]`

Comment: @garej Neat, that's even faster.